# Gap in the network waterfall, waiting for the Main thread

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm looking at the Network and Performance tabs in Chrome Dev Tools.
The goal is to explain the reason for the gap that I see in the waterfall between the 3 seconds and the 5 seconds marks.

[image]

Looking at the Performance tab I see that most of the time is spent waiting for the Main thread (the long trailing grey lines).

[image]

Where should I look further to explain why it is spending so much time waiting?
If I select that long grey line and look at the call stack I see a lot of purple.
Does this mean that the Main thread is waiting for rendering?
Is rendering done in the Main thread?

[image]